# print all foreach results

Tags: php, html

My code is 2 parts, the main contain the important php code (the body) and the second to print the output (as html)

I can't make it one...the output must print as html in the second part

The first part

```
<?php
   // The main code
   $w = explode('-', 'x1-x2-x3-x4');
   foreach($w as $n) {
      $s1 = $n;
   }
?>
```

The second

```
<?php
  // Print output here and must be here
  echo $s1;
?>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the output of foreach and it should be

```
x1
x2
x3
x4
```

But I only got `x4`. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by *part*? File? Code block?

Comment: no doesn't work..syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code keeps overwriting the value of `$s1`, therefore the last one is the only one that actually gets printed.

Turns out you don't need that foreach at all:

```
// first part
$w = explode('-', 'x1-x2-x3-x4');
$s1 = implode('<br>', $w);

// second part
echo $s1;
```

You can use `<br>` or `\n` depending on what `Content-type` you are sending on response.

Comment: That's so wow! I never thought of it like this :) +1 for the technique! This way he wouldn't need the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only print $s1 in the second part without looping or doing any other processing, you simply need to build the string $s1 first. In your case when the loop runs towards the last item, only that is stored in $s1. So the output is correct. Now, in order to output the whole thing as html, you can do something like this in the first part:

```
  foreach($w as $n)
      {
        $s1 .= $n . "<br />";
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way =)

```
echo str_replace('-', '<br>', 'x1-x2-x3-x4');
```

Answer (score 0):

you are overrididng all the content in foreach so you are getting only last one that is x4.

```
      foreach($w as $n)
      {
        $s1. = $n;
      }
      echo ($s1);
```

Comment: How it will show in next line you are not adding any <br /> tag

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this :)

```
echo str_replace('-','<br />','x1-x2-x3-x4');
```